# How to pass parameters to a JSP that will be loaded into a specific DIV on the current JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a JSP that has two divisons. The Left DIV has a bunch of links. Each link points to another JSP, which is to be loaded in the right DIV. However, I also want to pass some parameters to the JSP that would be loaded. As a simple example consider

CSS

```
<style>
#upleft {
    background: red;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width:  600px;
    float:left
}


#upright { 
    min-width:300px; 
    min-height:100px; 
    background:blue; 
    float:left  
}
#below { 
    min-height:300px; 
    min-width:400px; 
    background:green 
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="upleft">
        <a onclick="func()">Link </a>
    </div>
    <div id="upright"></div>
    <div id="below"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function func()
{
    alert("boo");
    $("#upright").load('tesdiv.jsp?par=9');
}
```

When I try this, nothing happens. The alert pops up.

Comment: Guessing you didn't name the page you are importing `tesdiv.jsp?par=9`          I would suggest some research: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: yes, you are right. the page is 'tesdiv.jsp' par is a parameter that i need to pass

Comment: `.load` brings a page into `#upright` so you are trying to pull a page named `tesdiv.jsp?par=9` into `#upright` which isn't valid.  I guess I have no idea what you end goal is, so I can't really help but I can tell you this is not proper usage of `.load()`

Comment: Look at the docs on http://api.jquery.com/load/ and implement it like the example that is titled `Example: Display a notice if the Ajax request encounters an error.` That way, you get an alert on failure or success and it will be easier to debug.

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look. actually my tesdiv.jsp needs the parameter to do some processing and based on that load some data. that data should be displayed on my main jsp

Comment: So you are importing a page that simply does some data manipulation?  Why can't you just add that into the main page?  Why add unnecessary complications?

Comment: tesdiv.jsp uses the parameter passed from the main jsp to dynamically create a table. tesdiv.jsp also has a datepicker for subsequent queries. Now, from this point on i only need the table that was created using the parameter passed. So, lets say by passing par = 9, i create some table X. Now, from this point on, when i pick some date on tesdiv.jsp, it should change table X's data. Had it been some other parameter, then we would be dealing with its corresponding table.

Comment: the other solution could be to have the datepicker on my main jsp itself, but i have not figured out how to dynamically create tables in that case

Comment: Is this parameter user input from a form or hardcoded or otherwise known ahead of time on the server-side (like loaded from a database)?  Because if its known on the server-side head of time, you could just use something like `<jsp:include page="tesdiv.jsp?par=9" />` rather than doing the Ajax. Of course, if you're going to be reloading it based on user input, it might make sense to do it in Ajax so the same method is always used to reload it (even for the initial load).

Comment: thanks @developerwjk yes the  parameter is entered by user